Checking for substring in foreignField in $lookup stage in mongo query
I am running on mongodb ^v5.5.0.
I am trying to build a pipeline that checks for my value for baseModel in another collections features.model field. But writing a regex statement inside of a $lookup is proving difficult.
I keep ending up with some variation of this error:
MongoServerError: PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: Failed to optimize pipeline :: caused by :: Failed to optimize expression :: caused by :: Invalid Regex in $regexMatch: nothing to repeat

This is my aggregation:
const pipeline = [
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'cloudstoreInventoryView',
          let: { baseModelVar: '$baseModel' },
          pipeline: [
            {
              $match: {
                $expr: {
                  // Use $regexMatch for matching with regex
                  $regexMatch: {
                    input: '$features.model', // Field in the foreign document
                    regex: { $concat: ['.*', '$$baseModelVar', '.*'] },
                    options: 'i', // Uncomment this line if you need case-insensitive matching
                  },
                },
              },
            },
          ],
          as: 'matchedModels',
        },
      },
      {
        $match: {
          source: 'rs',
          cleanSpecs: { $exists: true },
          // Ensure there are matched models
          matchedModels: { $ne: [] },
        },
      },
      {
        $project: {
          model: 1,
          cleanSpecs: 1,
          source: 1,
          matchedModels: 1, // Including matchedModels in the projection if you want to see them
        },
      },
      {
        $count: 'totalMatched',
      },
    ]

    console.log('Finding all matching models')
    const allMatchingModels = await infoCollection
      .aggregate(pipeline)
      .toArray()

I've tried to follow this guide and Ive seen a couple questions like this on stackoverflow but they were all generating their regex statically. Does anyone know what Im missing here?

Would be great to provide the sample input document and expected output. Thanks.
